# Viewport shading only for selected objects

Tags: 3d-view, objects, selection-tools

Is it possible to have different viewport shadings for the different objects in the scene based on, say their selection?

i.e. in Maya I can set my viewport objects all show in wireframe, except the currently selected one, which shows in shaded mode. Is that possible in blender?

Comment: I don't think it's possible out of the box, but I think it would be pretty simple with a bit of python.

Comment: ok, cool i will look into it, thnx

Comment: Isn't Display panel for such use?

Comment: you could do it that way, however that is not what i want because i want all the objects to be viewed in a single display panel but have different viewport shading characteristics.

Comment: @LeonCheung I think the OP wants the maximum draw type to dynamically change based on the selected object.

Comment: @gandalf3 Oh, something like the old behavior of matcap. I see. It's indeed not possible yet.